# Importing types for a relative path and associating this file with a declaration file

Tags: typescript

I have a browser app using non-rolled-up ESM. In order to work on GitHub Pages, I have a script to copy an ESM file out of `node_modules` to `vendor` and then I import that file in my app.

I am getting errors using `tsc` since the file does not have types found for it.

I want to find a way to import the types for this file in a manner that associates the types with the file. Using `typeRoots` or `include` in `tsconfig.json` to point to the original declaration file for the source of the copied file doesn't seem to help, apparently because this is not a global and these properties do not seem to rely on `package.json` (through `types`) to associate a declaration to a particular file (otherwise, I'm unclear on how an association is made).

One workaround I found was to use the bare specifier for the package in source and then use an import map to allow the browser to find the files (without necessitating a build step on my part). But I'm still curious if there's a way to do it with a relative file.